# Create child transactions using locking

Tags: hibernate, transactions, locking

```
@Service
public class YourEntityService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public String createSmallTransactions(Long entityId, int amount) {
        try {
            // Begin a transaction
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

            YourEntity entity = entityManager.find(YourEntity.class, entityId, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);

            if (entity == null) {
                return "Entity not found";
            }

            // Check if the sum of existing small transactions is less than the quantity
            int currentSum = getCurrentSum(entityId);

            if (currentSum + amount <= entity.getQuantity()) {
                // Update the entity before creating the SmallTransaction
                entity.setLastUpdated(LocalDateTime.now());

                SmallTransaction newTransaction = new SmallTransaction();
                newTransaction.setYourEntity(entity);
                newTransaction.setAmount(amount);

                entityManager.persist(newTransaction);

                // Commit the transaction
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

                return "Transaction created successfully";
            } else {
                // Rollback the transaction
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
                return "Transaction not allowed, quantity limit reached";
            }
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            // Handle concurrent modification
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            return "Error: Concurrent modification detected. Please retry.";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Rollback the transaction in case of other exceptions
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private int getCurrentSum(Long entityId) {
        // Query to calculate the sum of small transactions for an entity
        Number result = (Number) entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) FROM SmallTransaction t WHERE t.yourEntity.id = :entityId"
            )
            .setParameter("entityId", entityId)
            .getSingleResult();

        return result.intValue();
    }
}
```

I have a parent record and it has a attribute as amount. My api should allow creation of multiple child records, but the sum of child record amount should not exceed the parent record quantity.

Here I tried to do this using Hibernate versioning but updating the parent entity lastUpdated attribute each time before I create a child record. Is this a good approach for doing the same. Or should I use extensive approaches like FOR UPDATE db locking or LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_LOCK approach for making this consistent child record creation.